# Notepad++ How to configure settings so that all of the tabs align, and all text and spaces are equal size

Tags: notepad++

I am writing a python code using Notepad++ and am noticing that when I tab comments to the right of the code they are not lining up visually on the screen. Looking at the column number of the first character of each comment it appears that the columns don't align visually with their column number.

You can see that the comments on line 48 and 49 both start at column 49 but look out of line. Is there a way to change this so all the columns line up?

[image: example]

I tried changing different texts in the style configurator but none seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Change the font.

Comment: Visit menu => **Settings** -> **Style configurator**. See the [user manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/preferences/#style-configurator).

Comment: Which font has worked for you? I have tried many different fonts and they are all giving the same issue

Comment: How is this python related ? This is a kind preference that could be expressed for almost any text file in the world (except for a few old-timers programming languages with strict column alignement). Why is it even necessary ? the comments in the screenshot are absolutely useless as they convey pretty much the same meaning as the code line itself ... Fewer but better comments and less alignement-focus should do the trick.

Comment: Try “courier New” for example.

Comment: @Toto, "Courier New" works perfectly to fix the alignment, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a font where all characters (including spaces) are same length wide, they are called [monospace fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces).

One of most popular is `Courier new`.